# Using a foreach Loop for a Jagged String Array to display the Elements in it?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach, jagged-arrays

i am Using  for each Loop to a  Jagged String Array in order to display the Elements in it but it is not working and i have tried this code !

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[][] str = new string[5][];
            str[0] = new string[5];
            str[1] = new string[10];
            str[2] = new string[20];
            str[3] = new string[50];
            str[4] = new string[10];
            //Now store data in the jagged array
            str[0][0] = "Pune";
            str[1][0] = "Kolkata";
            str[2][0] = "Bangalore";
            str[3][0] = "The pink city named Jaipur";
            str[4][0] = "Hyderabad";
            //Lastly, display the content of each of the string arrays inside the jagged array
            foreach(string[] i in str)
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I have used a foreach loop but it is Printing

```
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
```

as output ....
So get me the Problem Solution Please as what i have to modify to get the Display as

```
Pune
Kolkata
Bangalore
The pink city named Jaipur
Hyderabad
```

Comment: you should do `Console.WriteLine(i[0].ToString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jagged array is an array of arrays - meaning you must have nested loops:

```
foreach(string[] i in str)
    foreach(string s in i)
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
             Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Another option is using linq's `SelectMany`:

```
foreach(var s in str.SelectMany(s => s).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Or, if you want to only display the first cell of each nested array:

```
foreach(string[] i in str)
    var s = i[0];
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Note I've added a check for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to avoid writing empty lines to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your code with this to loop through each array entry in your array :

```
 foreach(string[] i in str)
 {
     foreach(string s in i)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` itself is a string array and thus the result since `Tostring()` returning the default implementation of it. You need another loop to get to the real data item

```
foreach(string[] i in str)
{
  foreach(string j in i)
      Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jagged array is an array of arrays, so you need a second, nested, loop.

The second loop could be explicit, or hidden inside some method that loops over entries that you pass to it. For example, `string.Join` would combine all strings from a jagged row into a single string for printing:

```
foreach(string[] row in str)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", row));
```

You can use the same technique to eliminate the outer loop, too:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", str.Select(row => string.Join(" ", row))));
```

Comment: Actually, using string.Join is probably the best option. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the strings in all the arrays, and not get an exception:

```
foreach (string[] i in str)
    foreach (string s in i)
        if (s != null)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine(i[0].ToString());